# Drupal 7 views_embed_view function always using default parameters instead of new ones

Tags: php, drupal, drupal-7, drupal-views

I have created a view, view machine name is as 'list_events' and display machine name is 'black', I have also added three filters:

a) Content: Published (Yes)

b) Content: Type (= Event)

c) Content: Event Type (= Paid)

This displays fine in second sidebar.

Now I want to embed this view in sidebar one in one of the block. For this I created a custom module called as 'show event' and added following code in it::

```
function show_event_block_view($delta = '') {print_r($delta);
  if ($delta == 'event') {
    $viewName = 'list_events';
    $viewsHtml = views_embed_view($viewName, 'block', '1', 'Event', 'Free');
    return $viewsHtml;
  }
}
```

But it never considers my new parameter for example "Free", it always take "Paid" . (Please note first 2 parameters are same in both case).

Comment: Is it a contextual filter? Seems to me you would probably be better of creating a block view and use a contextual filter rather than your own module block.

Comment: @2pha Thanks, I got confused between 'Filter Criteria' and 'Contextual Filters'